# Unable to share an existing Self-Hosted Integration Runtime to a new Data Factory created using Terraform

Tags: azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm deploying an Azure Data Factory using Terraform using the below code in the terraform file:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "data-factory" {
  name                 =  var.usr-df-name
  resource_group_name  =  var.usr-resource-group-name
  location             =  var.usr-location
}
```

When I try to share an existing Self-Hosted Integration Runtime to this new data factory, I'm unable to find this new data factory in the search text box in the Sharing tab of the Runtime (+ Grant permission to another data factory). Can anyone advise on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Azure Data Factory needs to have a managed identity (System Assigned or User Assigned) to be able to share an existing Self-Hosted Integration Runtime on the new data factory. Add an identity argument to your code so that the data factory being created has a managed identity.

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "data-factory" {
  name                 =  var.usr-df-name
  resource_group_name  =  var.usr-resource-group-name
  location             =  var.usr-location
  identity {
     type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Once the data factory is created this way, you will be able to share an existing Interation runtime on this factory.